# Default write behaviour - O_TRUNC or O_APPEND?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls, file-descriptor

What is the default behaviour when you `open` a file with access mode `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`. Is the file opened in append mode or truncate mode? From the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> The argument flags must include one of the following access modes:
>   O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.
>   ...
>   In addition, **zero** or more *file creation* flags and *file status* flags can be bitwise-or'd in flags.

This sounds like `O_APPEND` and `O_TRUNC` flags are optional. So what does the following do?

```
void main ( void )
{
    int fd = open( "foo.txt", O_WRONLY );

    write( fd, "hello", 5 );

    close( fd );
}
```

Comment: You could have tried it easier than asking.  Additionally, since the bits are OR'd, per the man page, just look at the values of the two define (or ask your debugger) and see which one is zero.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to ask this question in a public forum where others could learn from it & the answers it received, @Jet-Blue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neither.

- By default the file is opened with the cursor positioned at the start. Writing overwrites the bytes at the beginning of the file.
- `O_TRUNC` causes the file to be truncated if it exists.
- `O_APPEND` causes writes to append to the end of the file instead of overwrite at the start. This flag is persistent. If you move the cursor elsewhere to read data it's always repositioned to the end of the file before each write.

The flags are orthogonal and are not mutually exclusive. You can even combine them if you want to initially truncate the file and ensure all later writes are always appends.

Comment: Note [per POSIX, you can use `pwrite()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) to write to any location in a file, even if it's opened with `O_APPEND`: "The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset (regardless of whether `O_APPEND` is set)."  That allows a file opened with `O_APPEND` to either have data atomically appended or atomically written to an arbitrary offset. Unfortunately, [`pwrite()` is broken on Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Thank you for reminding me! I've been angry about that WONTFIX bug ever since I first heard of it, and now that there's a `pwritev2` syscall with a flags argument I think it's finally fixable without breaking kernel API stability. Untested patch to add an option the userspace `pwrite` function can pass to fix it: http://ix.io/28aG

Answer (score 6):

When using the `O_WRONLY` flag by itself, it opens the file for writing, retains the existing file contents, and puts the file pointer at the start of the file.  Any writes overwrite existing content.

If you use `lseek` to reposition the file pointer, subsequent writes will occur at the repositioned offset.

This behavior contrasts with `O_TRUNC` which truncates the contents of the file when opened, and with `O_APPEND` which forces all writes to occur at the end of the file.